# Uexpected values inserted in table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `FunctionWeights` which contains data as follows:

[image: FunctionWeightsTable]

My query is as follows:

```
select @constVal = FunctionWeight from dbo.FunctionWeights where FunctionWeights.FunctionName = 'MatchCity'
Insert into #Temp2 select RowNumber,PercentMatch,@constVal, PercentMatch * @constVal from dbo.MatchCity(@City)
select * from #Temp2

select @constVal = FunctionWeight from dbo.FunctionWeights where FunctionWeights.FunctionName = 'MatchSSN'
Insert into #Temp2 select RowNumber,PercentMatch, @constVal, PercentMatch * @constVal from dbo.MatchSSN(@SSN)
select * from #Temp2
```

and so on................ for all function names.

Data-types for columns of #Temp2 are as follows:

```
Rownumber int not null,
ValFromFunc float(3)null,
FuncWeight float(3) null,
Percentage float(3) not null
```

However, The #Temp2 table after every insert has only 1 in FunctionWeight column for all the functionNames matched as shown above in queries.

The snapshot of `#Temp2` is as follows after insert for any function Name i.e FunctionWeight does not change as it should.

[image]

Comment: can you post the DDL for `FunctionWeights` and your TVF's

Comment: @Bijujose:Updated

Answer (score 1):

If the `FuncWeight` field in the `#Temp2` table is truly defined as `float(3)`, then the most likely problem is that the datatype of `@constVal` is `DECIMAL(x, 0)` or just `DECIMAL`. Either of those would round up the `0.7` values to be just `1`, though the `0.3` and `0.35` values would round down to `0`.

Nothing in that posted code or data indicates what could force *all* values of `FunctionWeight` to come out as `1`. Since some of the `FunctionWeight` values are `1`, I have to assume that the "snapshot of #Temp2" image was taken after testing `FunctionName` values that have non-`1` values for `FunctionWeight`.

Another possibility is that we are not being shown all rows in the `FunctionWeights` table and that there is duplication of the `FunctionName` values where the duplicated rows have a value of `1` for `FuncWeight`. In that case the last record read by the `select @constVal = FunctionWeight from dbo.FunctionWeights` query would be the value stored in `@constVal`, though that would not always be the "duplicated" row since there is no ORDER BY on the query.